# Mobile Browser emulator where Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice=True?

Tags: asp.net, mobile, browser-detection

I'm currently testing an ASP.NET Web Application on the "Opera Mobile" emulator.

I've got the following code for testing purposes:

```
Response.Write(Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
```

This is returning `False`

Are there emulators which act exactly like a mobile browser, so that this would return `True`?

It would be a bit of a pain if I have to release the application each time so that I can access it on my actual mobile phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don´t recommend you to use IsMobileDevice directly, because his db is not update. Microsoft launched [mdbf](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/), but now it´s abandoned.

You could override it using WURFL or 51degrees. But if you don´t need browser capabilities and you only need to know if it´s mobile device then you can use this [script](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/download/cs).

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using this component:

https://github.com/51Degrees/dotNET-Device-Detection

It detects mobile browsers far more reliable than the built in detection in .NET